# Python . CustomJS doesn't work js_on_change , Bokeh slider

Tags: python, bokehjs

There is code which has to show on map some data by let's say some number(year)
and problem is that CustomJs not even calling and data on slider doesn't work

```
def json_data(selectedYear):
   yr = selectedYear
   df_yr = df[df['year'] == yr]
   merged = gdf.merge(df_yr, left_on='country_code', right_on='code', how='left')
   merged.fillna('0', inplace=True)
   merged_json = json.loads(merged.to_json())
   json_data = json.dumps(merged_json)
   return json_data

geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=json_data(61))

palette = brewer['YlGnBu'][8]

palette = palette[::-1]

color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=palette, low=0, high=40, nan_color='#d9d9d9')

tick_labels = {'0': '0%', '5': '5%', '10': '10%', '15': '15%', '20': '20%', '25': '25%','30': '30%', '35': '35%','40': '>40%'}

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Country/region', '@country'), ('% obesity', '@per_cent_obesity')])

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=8, width=500, height=20,
                 border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0), orientation='horizontal',
                 major_label_overrides=tick_labels)
p = figure(title='Share of adults who are obese, 2016', plot_height=600, plot_width=950,     toolbar_location=None,
       tools=[hover])
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

p.patches('xs', 'ys', source=geosource, fill_color={'field': 'per_cent_obesity', 'transform': color_mapper},
      line_color='black', line_width=0.25, fill_alpha=1)

p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')

slider = Slider(title='Year', start=-21, end=61, step=1, value=61)


updatee = CustomJS(args=dict(slider=slider,source=geosource), code="""  
const yr = slider.value;
const new_data = json_data(yr);
const geosource.geojson = new_data;
const p.title.text = 'Share of adults who are obese, %d' % yr;
geosource.change.emit();
""")
```

but if I use instead of updatee this method:

```
def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    yr = slider.value
    new_data = json_data(yr)
    geosource.geojson = new_data
    p.title.text = 'Share of adults who are obese, %d' % yr
```

Slider value is changing but data isn't

```
slider.js_on_change('value', updatee)
layout = column(p, Column(slider))
curdoc().add_root(layout)

output_file("output_file_text.html") 
show(layout)
```